# Yii 1.1.15 login page with three text boxes

Tags: php

Can anyone give a single web page of login .
Login page should have three text boxes and one dripdown. 
name, username, password, usertype
plz give a zip foldar. i'm trying from last three days.

Comment: Please post your best attempt... Simply asking for a drop in solution is not the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly It hard to believe you need name, username, password and user-type all together for login. Anyways its personal requirement. Which framework do you use? if you are using `CodeIgnitor` then this might helpful for you.

http://www.developer.com/lang/php/codeignitor-create-a-login-process.html

If you need more help, post your proper requirement maybe I can help you.
Cheers!

Comment: he has mentioned that he is using yii